# Angular - Is possible to get the $http parameters?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

short question

I have this:

```
let promise = $http.get('/api/users');
```

Can I get the promise's parameters? Something like this:

```
let promise = $http.get('/api/users');

let parameters = promise.getParameters();

/*

parameters = {
   method: 'GET',
   url: 'api/users',
   // etc.
}

*/
```

I would like to make a Pagination service where I pass a promise and then I could change the url passing parameters (previous/next page etc.)

Thx.

edit:

I need to explain better:

I'd like to pass the "main" promise to a PaginationService.

```
this.paginator = {};

Paginator.make(this.paginator, function (page) {
   // this will be the "main" promise
   // page = 1
   return $http.get('/api/users', {
      params: {
         page: 1
      }
   });
});

// PaginatorService
this.make = function (scopePaginator, callback) {
   scopePaginator.next = function () {
      return callback(scopePaginator.current_page);
   };

   return callback().then(function (response) {
       // the response.meta contains all the data (current_page, etc.);

       angular.extend(scopePaginator, response.data);

       return scopePaginator;
   });

}
```

Something like this is what I'm doing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The configuration object that generated the request is part of the response object.

```
var promise = $http.get('/api/users');

promise.then(function onSuccess(response) {
    var config = response.config;
    console.log(config.method);
    console.log(config.url);
    console.log(config.params);
});
```

Thus successive $http calls can be chained from the promise.

```
promiseNext = promise.then(function onSuccess(response) {
    var config = response.config;
    vm.data[config.params.page] = response.data;
    config.params.page++;
    //return promise for chaining
    return $http(config);
};
```

---

### UPDATE

A function that returns pages until page number `n`:

```
var promiseUntilN = function(promise, n) {
    p = promise
        .then( function onSuccess(response) {
            var config = response.config;
            var page = config.params.page;
            vm.dataArray[page] = response.data;
            if ( page >= n ) {
                return vm.dataArray;
            } else {
                config.params.page++;
                return promiseUntilN($http(config), n);
            };
    return p;
};
```

Usage:

```
vm.dataArray = [];
var n = 10;
var promise1toN = promiseUntilN($http.get('/api/users',{page: 1}), n);

promise1toN.then( function onSuccess( dataArray ) {
    console.log(dataArray);
}).catch( function onReject(response) {
    var page = response.config.param.page;
    console.log("Error on fetch of page ", page);
});
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for, kind of.

Answer (score 0):

Why not create the parameters yourself?

```
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/api/users'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {...});
```

Answer (score 0):

You must set the `$http` request's parameters manually, but then you can pass it in for the request.

```
var parameters = {
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/someUrl'
};
var promise = $http.get(parameters);
```

More info [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).

Answer (score 0):

Better approach is to pass let's say, "offset" & "count" in your header on the api. Api will provide "offset" to "count" data with a count of total data on that table. What i mean is -

```
let promise = $http.get('/api/users',headers: { 'offset': 0, 'count': 10} );
```

and from api query data between offset to count and send this set of data -

```
{ yourProp1 : 'someData', yourProp2: 'someemail', count: 0, offset: 10, totalRowCount: 188}
```

Now use totalRowCount for your Pagination.