# Promise from recursive AJAX inside AJAX success

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got a controller invoking a service method. Inside that service method there is an AJAX call. In the success of the AJAX call I am invoking a different service method which has a recursive AJAX call depending on the results of the AJAX response. What I would like is to retrieve, in my controller, the FINAL result of the recursive AJAX call. (SEE UPDATED CODE AT BOTTOM)

**Controller:**

```
app.controller('myController', function($scope, myService) {

   $scope.getResults = function(){
      myService.lookup().then(function(data){
         console.log(data); //This returns just the 'lookup' data, but I want the final AJAX results of the recursive 'lookupUUID' service method here
      });
   }

   $scope.getResults();

});
```

**Service:**

```
app.service('myService', function() {
   var self = this;

   //This one is recursive 
   self.lookupUUID = function(lookupData){
      $.get('/another/url/here', function (data){
            if(!data[1]){
               self.lookupUUID(data);
            } else {
               return data;
            }
         }, 'json'
      )
   }

   self.lookup = function(){
      $.get('/some/url/here', function (data){
            if(!data[1]){
               return self.lookupUUID(data);
            } else {
               return data;
            } 
         }, 'json'
      );
   }

});
```

At the moment in my controller I just receive the `data` from the original AJAX call from the service's `lookup` method.

---

**UPDATED CODE:**

**Controller:**

```
app.controller('myController', function($scope, myService) {

   $scope.getResults = function(){
      myService.lookup().then(function(data){
         console.log(data);
      });
   }

   $scope.getResults();

});
```

**Service:**

```
app.service('myService', function($http) {
   var self = this;

   //This one is recursive 
   self.lookupUUID = function(lookupData){
      return (
         $http.get('/another/url/here', function (data){
               if(!data[1]){
                  return self.lookupUUID(data);
               } else {
                  return data;
               }
            }, 'json'
         ) //end of GET
      ); //end of return
   } //end of self.lookupUUID

   self.lookup = function(){
      return ( 
         $http.get('/some/url/here', function (data){
               if(!data[1]){
                  return self.lookupUUID(data);
               } else {
                  return data;
               } 
            }, 'json'
         ) //end of GET
      ); //end of return
   } //end of self.lookup

});
```

Unfortunately this still does not return the end result of the `lookupUUID` recursive method. I get the data back in my controller from the first AJAX `lookup` method.

Comment: Have you tried just adding `return` before the recursive call to `self.lookupUUID(data);`?

Comment: make sure this call `self.lookupUUID`

Comment: I'm actually getting console error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined". At the '.then' line of my controller.

Comment: that is because you are not returning promise

Comment: I've edited my question with updated code. I'm still having the issue with only retrieving the first data and not the final recursive data.

Comment: The `lookupUUID` function doesn't use the `lookupData` argument. It seems to be an infinite loop of XHR calls to `another/url/here`.

Comment: if you are getting data back from first look up it will never go to the lookupUUID because of your condition there?

Comment: Not necessarily, it is a condition on only a certain part of the data response, if `data[1]` is false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the assistance of @georgeawg and this [SO Question/Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38899861/angular-is-possible-to-get-the-http-parameters/38900086#38900086) I've been able to come up with a solution.

**SERVICE**

```
    self.lookupUUID = function(data, mode){
      var lookupUuidPromise = $http.get('/another/url/here');

      var p = lookupUuidPromise.then(function (response){
        if(response.data[1] != 0){
           return self.lookupUUID(response.data);
        } else {
           return response.data;
        }
      })

      return p;
   }

   self.lookup = function(domain, mode){
     var lookupPromise = $http.get('/some/url/here');

     var p = lookupPromise.then(function(data){
       if(data.data[1] != 0){
          return self.lookupUUID(data.data, mode);
       } else {
          return data.data;
       }
     });

     return p;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

> I'm actually getting console error: `"TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined"`. At the `.then` line of my controller

It is important to **return** at each level of the function hierarchy.

```
self.lookup = function(){
  //
  //return the promise
  return (
      $http.get('/some/url/here').then(function onSuccess(response){
          //return data to the success handler
          return response.data;
      }); 
  );
}
```

By failing to **return** a value to the `lookup` function, the function returns `undefined` which of course lacks a `.then` property.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I still seem to be getting the data back from the first AJAX call and not the recursive. I've updated my question with adjusted code.

Comment: @tnschmidt For an example of recursive `$http` calls see [this StackOverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38900086/5535245).

Comment: Thank you @georgeawg, that helped me finally come up with a working solution. I will post my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning resolve data then you are not able to use .then method, return promise instead, And you are using jquery which don't have the then method. Use $http instead which have the the then method and you can return promise.

> Note:- returning self.lookupUUID(data); on !data is not good idea return what ever coming and check it in controller instead.

```
 app.service('myService', function($http) {
       var self = this;

       //This one is recursive 
       self.lookupUUID = function(lookupData){
         return $http.get('/another/url/here', function (data){
                  return data;                  
             })
       }

       self.lookup = function(){
          $http.get('/some/url/here', function (data){
                if(!data[1]){
                   return self.lookupUUID(data);
                } else {
                   return data;
                } 
             });
       }

    });
```

**Controller**

```
 myService.lookup().then(function(data){
         console.log(data);
      },function(err){
   console.log(err)
 });
```

Comment: I appreciate the help. I think we are getting close. I have updated my question with some adjustments to my code. However, I am still receiving the data from the first AJAX call and not the end of the recursive AJAX call.

Answer (score -1):

This is done using $q service: (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

```
var deffered = $q.defer();
$timeout(function() {
    $timeout(function() {
        $timeout(function() {
           deffered.resolve({test : 'value'})
        }, 10)
    }, 10)
}, 10);
return deffered.promise;
```

P.S. Do not use jquery in angular unless you know 100% that you need to use it. Using $.get instead of $http service is weird.

Comment: That's noted about the $http and $.get. Thanks.